# Owl carousel and knockout.js binding within foreach binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, owl-carousel

He everyone, I know it is going to be specific question, but I have a problem using owl carousel with knockout.

```
 <div class="row">
            <div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel" data-bind="foreach: ads">
                <div class="ad-module">
                    <div data-bind="attr: { src: '/Content/images/' + Image }"></div>
                    <div data-bind="text: Title"></div>
                    <div data-bind="text: CityName"></div>
                    <div data-bind="text: CategoryName"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

If I delete `owl-carousel` class, everything works. And if I delete knockout foreach and enter images manually everything works. Did anyone ever had this problem before? Thanks.

Comment: You will need to use a custom binding handler for owl carousel.
Maybe this: https://github.com/Crunc/knockout-owlCarousel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call a specific function after you finish rendering the `foreach` items using:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: items, someOtherFunction">
```

The function that you want to call should be defined in `ko.bindingHandlers`

Here is a working example:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.owlCarouselInitiator = {
    init: function() {
     $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
          loop:true,
          nav:true,
          items : 3, 
        itemsDesktop : [1000,3],
        itemsDesktopSmall : [900,3],
        itemsTablet: [600,3]
      })
    }
};

ko.applyBindings({
    items: ko.observableArray([
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
        "4",
        "5",
        "6",
        "7",
        "9",
        "10"
    ])
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.owl-carousel .item {
  height: 120px;;
  background: #4DC7A0;
  padding: 1rem;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px;
}
.owl-carousel .item h4 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 120px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<ul class="owl-carousel" data-bind="foreach: items, owlCarouselInitiator">
    <li class="item"><h4 data-bind="text: $data"></h4></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need dynamically change items after view is rendered you can use custom knockout binding from  https://github.com/OleksiiStepanov/KnockoutOwlCarousel2

Usage example:

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" data-bind="owlCarousel: {data: items, options:{margin:10, nav:true }}">
    <div class="item" data-bind="text: $data"></div>    
</div>
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/s2reh01L/5/

Answer (score 1):

You can also you the [afterRender](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note-7-post-processing-or-animating-the-generated-dom-elements) callback to run initialise your owl carousel once your foreach has rendered.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: myItems, afterRender: initOwlCarousel }">
    <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
```